# group by a string column and datetime64[ns] column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following data and I would like to know: **Who was the first and last customer that each Driver pick-up for each day?**

[Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/194byxNkgr2e9r-IOEmSuu9gpZyw27G7j/view?usp=sharing)

This is how far I just got:

```
#Import libraries

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Open and clean the data
df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')  
df = df.drop(['Cod'], axis=1)
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'])
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'])

#the following code is to respond the following question:
#Who was the first and last customer that each Driver picked-up for each day?
#link to access the data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/194byxNkgr2e9r-IOEmSuu9gpZyw27G7j/view?usp=sharing

unique_drivers = df['Driver'].value_counts()

for driver in unique_drivers: 
    d= vdf.groupby('Driver').get_group(driver) 
    time = d['Start'][0] 
    first_customer = d['Customer'][0] 
    end = d['End'][0] 
    last_customer = d['Customer'][-1]
```

Comment: You should tag your question with whatever language you are using (python?). It will get seen by a **lot** more people that way.

Comment: @Nick Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @n1colas.m thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first sort by the column `Start` which includes the hour and minutes, ensuring that
multiple same day events are sorted correctly for the next step. Group the frame by `Driver` to find
the drivers pick up for each day.

Using `drop_duplicates` drop repeated values using the flag `keep="first"` to preserve only
the first values during the evaluation, similarly use `keep="last"` to preserve only the last (from a cluster of repeated values). This will produce unique dates for each driver, the first pick up and the last one for each day, then use the index from those days over the `Customer` column to get the customer's name.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
print(df)

# sort including HH:MM
df = df.sort_values("Start")

drivers_df = []
for gname, group in df.groupby("Driver"):
    dn = pd.DataFrame()

    # split to get date and time in two columns
    ts = group["Start"].str.split(expand=True)
    # remove duplicate days keeping the first occurance
    t_first = ts.drop_duplicates(subset=[0], keep="first")
    # remove duplicate days keeping the last occurance
    t_last = ts.drop_duplicates(subset=[0], keep="last")

    dn["Date"] = t_first[0]
    dn["Driver"] = gname
    dn["Num_Customers"] = ts[0].groupby(ts[0]).count().values
    # use the previous obtained indices over the "Customer" column
    dn["First_Customer"] = df.loc[t_first.index, "Customer"].values
    dn["Last_Customer"] = df.loc[t_last.index, "Customer"].values
    drivers_df.append(dn)

dn = pd.concat(drivers_df)
# remove to sort by driver's name
dn = dn.sort_values("Date")
dn = dn.reset_index(drop=True)
print(dn)
```

Output from **dn**

```
         Date             Driver  Num_Customers                 First_Customer                  Last_Customer
0   5/10/2020      Javier Pulgar              1   100998 - MARA MIRIAN BEATRIZ   100998 - MARA MIRIAN BEATRIZ
1   5/10/2020   Santiago Muruaga              1       103055 - ZANOTTO VALERIA       103055 - ZANOTTO VALERIA
2   5/10/2020   Martín Gutierrez              1  105645 - PAWLIW MARTA SOFI...  105645 - PAWLIW MARTA SOFI...
3   5/10/2020      Pablo Aguilar              2   102737 - GONZALVE DE ACEVEDO   102737 - GONZALVE DE ACEVEDO
4   5/10/2020      Carlos Medina              1       102750 - COOP.DE TRABAJO       102750 - COOP.DE TRABAJO
5   5/11/2020    Facundo Papaleo              6   101209 - FARMACIA NAZCA 2602           105093 - BIO HERLPER
6   5/11/2020  Franco Chiarrappa             15  100288 - SAVINI LUCIANA MARIA       102690 - GIOIA ELIZABETH
7   5/11/2020     Hernán Navarro             14  106367 - FARMACIA BERAPHAR...      102631 - SPALVIERI MARINA
8   5/11/2020      Pablo Aguilar              9       102510 - CAZADORFARM SCS       101482 - JOAQUIN MARCIAL
9   5/11/2020      Daniel Godino              7  103572 - GIRALDEZ ALICIA OLGA  103363 - CADELLI ROBERTO JOSE
10  5/11/2020     Hernán Urquiza              1  105323 - GARCIA GERMAN REI...  105323 - GARCIA GERMAN REI...
11  5/11/2020     Héctor Naselli             19      103545 - FARMACIA DESANTI    102257 - FARMA NUOVA S.C.S.
12  5/11/2020   Santiago Muruaga             12       101735 - ALEGRE LEONARDO       500014 - Drogueria DIMEC
13  5/11/2020      Javier Pulgar              2     101009 - MIGUEL ANGEL MARA  103462 - DRAGONE CARLOS AL...
14  5/11/2020   Atilano Aguilera              1        104003 - FARMACIA SANTA        104003 - FARMACIA SANTA
15  5/11/2020            Muletto              3    101359 - FARMACIA COSENTINO        105886 - NEGRI GREGORIO
16  5/11/2020   Martín Venturino              8  102587 - JANISZEWSKI MATIL...      102672 - BORSOTTI GUSTAVO
17  5/11/2020   Martín Gutierrez              1  105645 - PAWLIW MARTA SOFI...  105645 - PAWLIW MARTA SOFI...
18  5/11/2020      José Vallejos             13  102229 - LANDRIEL MARIA LO...  105721 - SOSA NANCY EDITH ...
19  5/11/2020    Edgardo Andrade              9        101524 - FARMACIA M Y A         101217 - MARISA TESORO
20  5/11/2020      Carlos Medina             14   105126 - QUISPE MURILLO RODY  100538 - MAXIMILIANO CAMPO...
21  5/11/2020     Javier Torales              1     200666 - CLINICA BOEDO SRL     200666 - CLINICA BOEDO SRL
22  5/12/2020     Hernán Urquiza              8  105293 - BENSAK MARIA EUGENIA     103005 - BONVISSUTO SANDRA
23  5/12/2020     Miguel Quilici             17         102918 - BRITO NICOLAS         102533 - SAMPEDRO PURA
...
...
```